# Throwing error when defining geometry in region reduction in image collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am getting this error in reference to my geometry definition:

```
Image (Error)
Collection.first: Error in map(ID=LC08_001004_20140609):
Image.reduceRegion: Provide 'geometry' parameter when aggregating over an unbounded image.
```

This is the segment of code it is reacting too:

```
var out = img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC', bandList).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
    geometry: ee.Geometry(img.geometry().buffer(-5000)), 
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1000000000
    }) ;
```

The input images to this function are Landsat 8 tiles that are going to through atmospheric/topographic correction. I don't know why the line `ee.Geometry(img.geometry().buffer(-5000))` for geometry isn't working. The desired code would run the reduction on all of the images in the landsat image collection with their own unique geometries based on their geolocations.

This is the link to the code w/ the error: https://code.earthengine.google.com/49ce3acaf6c6ed03c10f269078f26bff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out following code and it works without any issue. My out variable is similar to yours; where I tested different buffer negative values (if they are too high in absolute value so, offset and scale are always computed null).

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
          [[[2.1694671053232417, 47.87080972692645],
          [2.1694671053232417, 47.86847786202571],
          [2.1748100656809077, 47.86847786202571],
          [2.1748100656809077, 47.87080972692645]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
                  .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-12-31')
                  .filterBounds(geometry);

var img = dataset.first().clip(geometry).select(['B3', 'B4']);

var imageVisParam = {"opacity":1,
                     "bands":["B4"],
                     "min":0.0717,
                     "max":0.1030,
                     "gamma":1};

var buffer = img.geometry().buffer(-100);

Map.centerObject(geometry);
Map.addLayer(img, imageVisParam, 'B4 band');
Map.addLayer(buffer, {color: 'red'}, 'buffer');

var out = img.select('B4', 'B3').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
    geometry: ee.Geometry(img.geometry().buffer(-100)), 
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 1000000000
    });
    
print(out);
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got result of following image. Buffer layer and clipped image are both added to Map Canvas.

[image]

By using -5000 for buffer and without any clip, result ([link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/bad86f92b90e1f02941cbdca17a2e4e6)) was as follows:

[image]

So, issue is because you are not adequately producing bounded images (img_plus_ic_mask2) mapping Image Collection.

**Editing Note:**

Based in your added link, I founded out several error sources. I fixed all of them except one. For some reason, **out_c** is not computed adequately. So, I assumed arbitrarily for this variable the value of 3 and expected images (c_corr8) can be obtained without any error. This is an extract of corrections (complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/dc70f2363ef9cebae850cabcae032fc5)):

```
  function apply_Ccorr(bandList){
    var method = 'c';
    var out = img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC', bandList).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.linearFit(), // Compute coefficients: a(slope), b(offset), c(b/a)
    geometry: ee.Geometry(ee.Image(img_plus_ic_mask2).geometry().buffer(-500)), 
    scale: 30,
    maxPixels: 2e10
    }) ;
    var out_a = ee.Number(out.get('scale'));
    var out_b = ee.Number(out.get('offset'));
    var out_c = 3 //ee.Number(out.get('offset')).divide(ee.Number(out.get('scale')));
    
    //apply the c model correction
    var c_output = img_plus_ic_mask2.expression("((image * (cosZ + cvalue)) / (ic + cvalue))", {
      'image': img_plus_ic_mask2.select(bandList),
      'ic': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('IC'),
      'cosZ': img_plus_ic_mask2.select('cosZ'),
      'cvalue': out_c
    });//.rename(bandList+'corr_'+method)
    
    var keyTopoCorrMeth = 'TopoCorr_Method';
    var keya = bandList+'a';
    var keyb = bandList+'b';
    var keyc = bandList+'c';
    
    return ee.Image(c_output).setMulti({TopoCorr_Meth: method, TopoCorr_a: out_a, TopoCorr_b: out_b, TopoCorr_c: out_c}).copyProperties(img_plus_ic_mask2);
  }
  
  var img_Ccorr = ee.Image(bandList.map(apply_Ccorr)).addBands(img_plus_ic.select('IC'));
  var bandList_IC = ee.List([bandList, 'IC']).flatten();
  return img_Ccorr.unmask(img_plus_ic.select(bandList_IC))
                  .addBands(mask1.rename('initMask'))
                  .addBands(mask2.rename('corrMask'));
};
```

Comment: I understand your code and answer, but would you mind looking at my link? I still don't understand why I'm getting this error. https://code.earthengine.google.com/49ce3acaf6c6ed03c10f269078f26bff

Comment: Please, see my **Editing Note**.